# Name of this sequence of numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16, 18, 24, 27, 32, 36, 48, 54, 64, 72, 81, 96, 108, 128, 144, 162, 192, 216, 243, 256, 288, 324, 384, 432, 486, 512, ...

It has friends, one of them that looks like: 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 16, 20, 25, 32, 40, 50, 64, 80, 100, 125, 128, 160, 200, 250, 320,

Every number of the sequence contains only divisors found lower in the sequence, aside from two prime numbers at the start of the sequence.

Comment: OEIS gives the following: http://oeis.org/A003586

Comment: The second sequence is apparently the numbers with no prime factor different from $2$ and $5$

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is the sequence of numbers with no prime factors larger than $3$, called 3-smooth numbers: https://oeis.org/A003586.

Found via the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences: https://oeis.org/.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I stepped in, is this OK?